# Trying To Avoid Reading a File Twice

Tags: c#

I am parsing a text file that can be up to 35MB in size.

I currently have this code:

```
const string show_BLOCK_DELIMITER = "show ";
const string Show_BLOCK_DELIMITER = "Show ";
const string Begin_SHOW_HW_DELIMITER = @"show hardware internal errors";
```

and this logic that controls what to capture:

```
 if ((line == null) || (trimmed.StartsWith(show_BLOCK_DELIMITER))
  ||   (trimmed.StartsWith(Show_BLOCK_DELIMITER))  
|| (trimmed.Contains(Begin_SHOW_HW_DELIMITER)))
  {
     //stuff happens here
   }
```

The way I capture is read the file and when I hit a line that starts with 'show' or 'Show' I check it to see if it is what I want to capture. If so I start capturing until the next line that starts with 'show' or 'Show'.  The new code is supposed to capture stuff between the constant 'Begin_SHOW_HW_DELIMTER' except here is is a sample of the input.  What I should get is 2 blocks, or strings, each one starting with "Module-N#" Since those lines with fc-mac in them start with 'show' but aren't in the list of what I want to capture the code thinks it is a new block and they don't get captured.  At this point I am wondering about a separate method to handle this new part and just reading the file twice.  The if/else statements are already pretty convoluted.

module-1# show hardware internal errors

`show hardware internal fc-mac port 1 interrupt-counts`

`show hardware internal fc-mac port 2 interrupt-counts`

module-2# show hardware internal errors

`show hardware internal fc-mac port 1 interrupt-counts`

`show hardware internal fc-mac port 2 interrupt-counts`

Comment: Where is the part where you're reading the file twice?

Comment: @minitech Sorry,  I was unclear. There isn't one, yet. I am trying to avoid doing that but wondering if it is any less efficient than adding more checks to my existing already convoluted if/else.  I would parse the file once fore the existing captures I have, then parse it again for the new captures I want.  The new input breaks the existing logic without a few additional special-case checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having a performance problem, your conditional statements are a whole lot less expensive than disk reads, so reading the file twice will ultimately reduce performance.

Now, complex conditional statements do reduce maintainability, and introduce possibilities for bugs.

What you could do, is you could read the file into memory(just load all the lines into an array.), and reading the file twice would take less time, but you would be using more memory.

Comment: Not a performance problem just a problem with the existing logic.  Reading the file twice wouldn't be super efficient.   Complex conditionals have their own problems.  What I could do with an array is read the entire file in, search for beginning/ending indexes then capture those as a block.  That would mean reworking the existing logic but I think that has to be done anyway.